# Prevent XSS - Remove <Script> Tags in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, json.net, .net-core, xss

I am trying to prevent JavaScript injections via `JSON` in a `JObject` like so:

```
  public class JsonService : IJsonService
  {
    private JsonSerializerSettings _jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
      StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml
    };

    public JObject SanitizeJson(JObject jsonToSanitize) {

      string sanitizedJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonToSanitize, _jsonSerializerSettings);
      JObject sanitizedJson = JObject.Parse(sanitizedJsonString);

      return sanitizedJson;

    }
```

This is all good fun, until I realize that my input looks like this:

```
{
"submission": {
    "firstName": "<script>document.write('script kiddie');</script>",
    "birthday": "05/21/2015",
    "submit": []
  }
}
```

My "`sanitizedJsonString`" looks like this:

> "{\"submission\":{\"firstName\":\"\u003cscript\u003edocument.write(\u0027script
>   kiddie\u0027);\u003c/script\u003e\",\"birthday\":\"05/21/2015\",\"submit\":[]}}"

And my "`sanitizedJson`" looks like this:

```
{{
  "submission": {
    "firstName": "<script>document.write('script kiddie');</script>",
    "birthday": "05/21/2015",
    "submit": []
  }
}}
```

Note that while the formatting into a string does escape the javascript, it's right back in the code the moment I turn it back into a `JObject`. In other words, a script gets saved to the database. My end goal is not to have form submissions (that come through as JSON I don't control) get saved in the db. I DO need to serialize the string back into a `JObject` on trip back to client, so I need it cleaned from the JObject. I am tempted to do `str.Replace("<","")`, etc, but that's obviously not a real solution.

How do I accomplish cleaning out the `<script>` tags?

Additions from comments:

1. I am getting JSON from third-party front-end.
2. I am sending back JSON to third-party front-end, some of which will be rendered as html.

Edit 2:

Tried `AntiXSS` via NuGet, it is not compatible with .NET Core: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.NET_AntiXSS_Library

Comment: Why is having script tags in your database a problem? It should only cause an issue if you insert it into an HTML document without performing apropriate escaping for HTML.

Comment: @Quentin This is saving to a User record. Then it gets displayed back to the user when they want to edit their name. Obviously this is harmless enough, until we get to fields shared by multiple users.

Comment: Well then apply context appropriate escaping when you bring them into the HTML context.

Comment: So what's wrong with displaying the data back to the user? Or a different user? If you escape it for HTML (which you should, you're inserting user inputted text into an HTML document) then there is no security problem. It is nonsensical data, but trying to prevent people from entering nonsense through filtering is fruitless.

Comment: @CBroe 1. Why would I want crap data in the database that's used by 5+ different apps/sites. 2. What is "appropriate escaping"?

Comment: @Quentin I have to send JSON back to a third party, which then renders the JSON in their html. I need the JSON clean. The whole problem/point of this q is the json.net "cleaning" utility isn't cleaning anything.

Comment: If they expect you to be providing JSON containing HTML instead of JSON containing plain text, then perform normal HTML escaping before putting the data in the JSON.

Comment: Note that that's exactly what I am trying to do. When I serialize it into a JObject, it turns the escaped characters back into html tokens, e.g. into `<` - it's all in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to reject the input JSON when you see any suspicious characters in it. But when that is not possible, we can at least validate it for XSS attack. 
I was in the same boat & I found a pointer in another question here: [AntiXSS in ASP.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923431/antixss-in-asp-net-core)

Hope you can carve out your solution from this reference as well.